# Adding property only if value is set

Tags: angular

So I'm looking for a way to only add an `href` property to anchor tags (`<a></a>`) if a value is set in a config object so that the page doesn't reload when the anchor tag is clicked unless a url is specified for that menu item.

Right now my markup looks like:

```
<a [href]="link.url ? link.url : '#'">{{link.title}}</a>
```

And of course I could also use the `"return javascript:;"` syntax as well, but ideally I would like to be able to avoid putting the href property on the anchor tag in the first place.

I also tried using the markup

```
<a [href]="link.url">{{link.title}}</a>
```

By simply not defining a url for the given link, however this gives me an empty href attribute like so: `<a href>Title</a>` which still results in a page reload.

Ultimately I would like to see the following:

URL Defined: `<a href="/url">title</a>`

URL Not Defined: `<a>title</a>`

Comment: Did you try:  [href]="link.url|'#'" ?

Comment: That literally does the same thing as `<a [href]="link.url ? link.url : '#'">{{link.title}}</a>`, it's just a little less semantic.  The goal is to have no `href` property at all unless there is a valid url defined.

Comment: Got you. Didn't realize you actually want to not assign it if it is missing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<a [attr.href]="link.url">{{link.title}}</a>
```

Comment: Glad I could helped. Just looked for "angular2 conditional property" and wajam!

Comment: Btw, angular2 has quite an elaborate syntax, for example: (keydown.enter) or (keyup.c) etc...